# Asp.Net MVC Controller Multi-Language

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there a way to make `http://myapp.com/Orders`, `http://myapp.com/Pedidos`, `http://myapp.com/Solicetudes` reach the same `OrdersController`??? Maybe something like

```
[AlternativeNames("Pedidos","Solicitudes","Bla","Ble")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this at the Route level.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute("Order-Controller-Spanish", "Pedidos", new { controller = "Order" });
    routes.MapRoute("Order-Controller-English", "Orders", new { controller = "Order" });
}
```

In your global.asax :

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```